# How to restore "wheel" user/group?

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, osx-el-capitan, user-groups

I deleted `wheel` group in HDD "get info/permissions" wrongly thinking it was hacker. I now see that my Mac is running akwardly these days. How can I restore or recover "natural" or previous HDD user/group permissions? I can't find anywhere the "wheel" user/group, neither can see it as an option for adding again.
Please any help will be usefull. I am quite ignorant in these stuff, but I can follow directions.
I am running a MacBook Pro with  OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
Thanks!

Comment: Try [this solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4011246). It's from 2012, but if it still applies then wheel wasn't really deleted and can be restored. Let me know if it does work and I'll put up an answer.

Comment: Hi @harrymc It did work! Thank you so much. By the way... I can't remember if I also did the stupid "erasing wheel" from my HD Backup (a partition made with Time Machine few months ago) or from the "applications" "documents" or other File or Folder. Should I do just the same with these other files/folders? should I recheck in batCHmod the X and R of "HD Backup", Applications, Documents and any other (or every other) file and folder? Thank you very much. Very helpfull and Time saving your wonderfull answer. Lots of good karma for you! =)

Comment: I added an answer to be accepted.

Comment: Accepted @harrymc ! So, do you think I shoud recheck in batCHmod the X and R of "HD Backup", Applications, Documents folders?

Comment: To answer that I have needed to experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no real way to delete the wheel, it wasn't really deleted and
can be restored using the the post
 [HELP! Deleted "wheels" user - how do I fix?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4011246)

**Solution 1**

> Use [BatChmod](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/index.html) - drag
>   the icon for the boot disk into the File field, and recheck the R and
>   X boxes for the wheel group. (Don't check Apply to enclosed folders
>   and files!) The subsequent password authentication dialog still
>   worked.

**Solution 2**

> ```
> $ su
> Password:
> sh-3.2# chmod 755 /
> sh-3.2# exit
> exit
> $ ls -ldeO /
> drwxr-xr-x  34 root  wheel  - 1224 Jun  2 18:59 /
> ```
>
> sudo now worked again as well:
>
> ```
> $ sudo ls -ldeO /
> Password:
> drwxr-xr-x  34 root  wheel  - 1224 Jun  2 18:59 /
> ```
>
> Using
>
> ```
> chmod 755 /
> ```
>
> in single-user mode would presumably have worked as well.

Comment: This is interesting, but can’t one just reboot into recovery mode and repair permissions?